# How can I integrate xajax with CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, xajax

Did anybody successfully integrate xajax with CakePHP? I've found 'Cakex plugin', but I'd like to hear some options.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into using xajax in the past, and I'm happier having learned jQuery to handle all ajax operations.